# Radon function result's repeatability

Tags: functions, bugs, image-processing

**Bug introduced in 9.0.0 and fixed in 9.0.1**

---

I want to get a Hough transform of some edged image.

When I compare the same transformation on the same image I got different results.

```
i = 0; While[i < 10, i++; Print[Radon[imgEdged, Method -> "Hough"] == 
               Radon[imgEdged, Method -> "Hough"]]]
True
True
True
False
True
True
False
False
False
True
```

Why isn't repeatability provided in result of this function?

Update:

imgEdged = [image: edged image]

Comment: Hi jhilary, welcome to Mathematica.SE! Could you please consider uploading your `imgEdged` so others can have a full view on your question?

Comment: I cannot test this (`Radon` is new) but you may try setting e.g. `SeedRandom[1]` before every use of `Radon` in case the latter makes use of random numbers without using `BlockRandom` (which also might be applicable).

Comment: I find Radon[] is giving consistent results for a set of test images in MMa 8.0 Perhaps your particular image has some particularity. Please post a link to it.

Comment: I get a different Radon transform every time... ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vfevq.png)

Comment: I tried post image in question, but they said that not enough reputation http://i.stack.imgur.com/UeSlT.jpg

Comment: > try setting e.g. SeedRandom[1] -- I tried, but it doesn't help. I think that Radon doesn't use randomization at all

Answer (score 7):

I think I found more hints on what might explain the fact that `Hough` gives different results each time it is called. But this is too small to fit in a comment.

This is assuming the implementation by *Mathematica* is as explained in the Wikipedia article for [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform). The `Hough` implementation uses (from the link)

> The Hough transform algorithm uses an array, called an accumulator, to 
>       detect the existence of a line $y = mx + b$

Then later on it says:

> the number of page swaps required for this will be very demanding because 
>       the accumulator array is used in a randomly accessed fashion

Notice the word `randomly accessed`. This is the key.

It seems to work in a fashion similar to Monte Carlo method for numerical integration in the sense only that it uses randomness to do its work for speed vs. quality.

But since using `SeedRandom[1]` did not resolve the differences between calls as can be seen here:

```
With[{imgEdged = Image[CellularAutomaton[30, {{1}, 0}, 40], "Bit"]},
 Reap[Do[
   SeedRandom[1];
   im1 = Radon[imgEdged, Method -> "Hough"];
   SeedRandom[1];
   im2 = Radon[imgEdged, Method -> "Hough"];
   Sow[im1 == im2], {i, 100}]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

My guess now is that `Radon[]`, or the function that implements the `Method->Hough` does not use the same random number generator that `SeedRandom[]` resets (the global one), but its own, in the Kernel, and it forgets to reset its own at random number generator at start of each call? Just a guess, since nothing else seems to make sense ;)

You might also want to look at [Randomized Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_Hough_transform)

Comment: The link you shared mentions this — Hough generally uses polling and binning, and I presume it uses a random initialization each time.

Comment: Interesting. I still get `True` always http://i.stack.imgur.com/a4Y6b.png

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi Mma 8.0 on WinXp

Comment: I'm not convinced on the "random access" point. In computer engineering this simply means that the access pattern is not predictable by memory controller, not literally that the access occurs at a randomly chosen point. Basically it is the antonym of "sequential" in this context, although modern processors can predict some nonsequential access patterns as well.

Answer (score 7):

That was a bug which got fixed in Mathematica 9.0.1.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Nasser I search about probablistic hough transform. Maybe it used in Mathematica implementation for speeding-up. 
I found good explanation here: http://www.cvmt.dk/education/teaching/f09/VGIS8/AIP/hough_09gr820.pdf

> The Hough transform is not a fast algorithm for ﬁnding inﬁnite lines in images of a certain size.
>   Since additional analysis is required to detect ﬁnite lines, this is even slower. A way to speed up
>   the Hough Transform and ﬁnding ﬁnite lines at the same time is the Progressive Probabilistic
>   Hough Transform (PPHT). The idea of this methood is to transform randomly selected
>   pixels in the edge image into the accumulator. When a bin in the accumulator corresponding
>   to a particular inﬁnite line has got a certain number of votes, the edge image is searched along
>   that line to see if one or more ﬁnite line(s) are present. Then all pixels on that line are removed
>   from the edge image. In this way the algorithm returns ﬁnite lines. If the vote threshold is low
>   the number of pixels to evaluate in the accumulator gets small

And important part:

> An issue with this algorithm is, that severel runs may may yield diﬀerent results. This can be
>   the case if many lines share pixels. If two lines cross, the ﬁst line to be detected removes the
>   common pixel (and a band around it) resulting in a gab in the other line. If many lines cross,
>   then many pixels can miss in the last lines, and the votes in the accumulator may not reach the
>   threshold.

So If you want after hough transform get expected lines, I think it's not very useful use hough transform (*ImageLines* function use Hough transform method inside (or RANSAC, which is randomized too)).

For example [OpenCV hough lines](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghlines#houghlines) provide choice which algorithm used in lines' search.